# TypeError string indices must be integers - python json dict

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, python-requests

i keep getting TypeError: string indices must be integers in my python code . this is the error i getting

```
File "C:lifebot\symptoms.py", line 127, in getConditionfromText if symptom['Name'].lower() == el['label'].lower(): TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

this my code **symtoms.py** part that give error

```
     # APIMEDIC Diagnosis Client
        self._diagnosisClient = apidemic.DiagnosisClient(username, password, authUrl, language, healthUrl)
        
        # List of all available symptoms from Apimedic API.
        self.availableSymptoms = self._diagnosisClient.loadSymptoms()

        # Client for database transactions and requests
        # self._databaseClient = database.Database()

    def getSymptoms (self):
        '''
        Return dictionary of all (ID, Name) pairs from apimedic api.
        '''
        result = dict()
        for symptom in self.availableSymptoms:
            result[symptom['ID']] = symptom['Name']
       
        return result

def getConditionfromText(self, text):
        found_symptoms = ""
        text = text.replace(' ', '+')
        url = 'https://polar-refuge-89127.herokuapp.com/text={}'.format(text)
        USER_AGENT = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
        result = requests.get(url, headers=USER_AGENT)
        page = ast.literal_eval(result.text)
        # Concatenate all symptoms present in text
        for symptom in self.availableSymptoms:
            for el in page:
                if symptom['Name'].lower() == el['label'].lower():
          
                    found_symptoms += ' ' + str(symptom['ID'])
```

full code view is here
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gopimys/lifebot/master/apidemic.py
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gopimys/lifebot/master/symptoms.py

this my json dict

```
[{"ID":10,"Name":"Abdominal pain"},{"ID":238,"Name":"Anxiety"},{"ID":104,"Name":"Back pain"},{"ID":75,"Name":"Burning eyes"},{"ID":46,"Name":"Burning in the throat"},{"ID":170,"Name":"Cheek swelling"},{"ID":17,"Name":"Chest pain"},{"ID":31,"Name":"Chest tightness"},{"ID":175,"Name":"Chills"},{"ID":139,"Name":"Cold sweats"},{"ID":15,"Name":"Cough"},{"ID":207,"Name":"Dizziness"},{"ID":244,"Name":"Drooping eyelid"},{"ID":273,"Name":"Dry eyes"},{"ID":87,"Name":"Earache"},{"ID":92,"Name":"Early satiety"}]
```

Comment: Do you know what `el` is evaluating to in the expression `for el in page:`?  It appears that `el` is evaluating to a string, so the attempt to index it with 'label' is triggering the exception.

Comment: when input goes through (my NLP) this url https://polar-refuge-89127.herokuapp.com/text={} it returns this for eg: {"data":[{"label":"back pain","value":0.987453548451465}],"size":1} . from label which is el['label'] i get symptom name  symptom['Name']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through this link to get result data : `"https://polar-refuge-89127.herokuapp.com/text={}"`
Value for page returned from url is :

```
{"data":[{"label":"back pain","value":0.5},{"label":"abdominal pain","value":0.5}],"size":2}
```

Change this line of code `"for el in page"` with `"for el in page['data']"` in getConditionfromText method, it will fix this error